# Finding a file in a root directory of jar exported from Eclipse for JUNIT testing

Tags: java, eclipse, file, jar, junit4

In my Eclipse JUNIT test I have several text input files that are opened  by

```
new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFileName));.
```

They are placed in the root directory of the project After exporting this project to jar these files are placed to the jar root directory.
I run the JUNIT test from LINUX as

```
java -cp "<my jar>:junit-4.8.2.jar:jaxb-impl.jar" junit.textui.TestRunner <test class name>
```

However, in this case I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException
What is the best way to fix this problem on LINUX and at the same time still able to run the tests from Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Class#getResourceAsStream() method to load classpath resources:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myfile.txt");
```

You can convert it to `Reader` interface using `InputStreamReader` adapter.

Comment: The same comment as for the previous answer - can I have the same directory structure?

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question, but you said that your file is in JAR. So it is effectively available by the class loader

Comment: yes, but this jar is in the root directory of this Jar.  I need to move it to src direcotry (sourcepath) to invoke the class loader

Comment: usually you put all required resources to src/main/resources and they are packed into JAR together with classes, if you use this file for testing purposes only, you need to put it into src/test/resources

Answer (score 1):

What I want was achieved by adding * to the classpath and putting properties file into run directory. This feature started in Java 6.  Then the properties file is achievable in classpath and is achieved both from Eclipse and command prompt running.  It is a little different from my question – the properties file is not in jar, but that is what is needed.  Plus, one can edit the properties file outside of Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Class method [getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

There's also an other issue on stackoverflow see:
[getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Comment: Thank you. In this case I will need to move files to a directory that is available by the class loader.  Is it possible to have the same directory structure as now?